# 500 Internal server error in Laravel for every route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My laravel application was working very fine, until I installed entrust.

Now, all my routes which are grouped gives me 500 server error. However, the route when placed out of group gives me the desired result.

```
Route::get('ticker', 'UsersController@index');
```

This gives me perfect result.

However, this doesn't.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function() {


    Route::get('ticker', 'UsersController@index');
});
```

What has gone wrong? I am unable to figure out. I also tried logging errors in apache, but doesn't give me a error in the log file.

Comment: What do you see when you execute `php artisan route:list`? Also, if you get a 500 error, you should look into Laravel's error log since the issue is not with Apache.

Comment: There is no error log in laravel too. And route:list shows the expected output - all routes defined

Comment: There is an error log in Laravel, at storage/logs/

Comment: I meant to say, there is no log for 500 server error in Laravel' log

Comment: Still, it would be helpfull to see, what the laravel log is logging. We need more information

Comment: can you create a simple route ?? Route::get('a', function() { return "ok"; } );

Comment: Can you pastebin your .htaccess and the error log?

Comment: If the error occurred after installing entrust, then I would suspect that is the problem. Can you tell us more about entrust?

Comment: Problem Solved! I just did composer auto-load